# Set vertical scrollbar position depends on selected item in the list

Tags: .net, wpf, events, triggers, scrollbars

In my little app there's a button that once getting clicked, the fifth item in the listview getting selected.

the problem is that its out of the listview scope and I would like the vertical scroll bar to slide down to the so I can see the selected item.

How can I do that ?

[image]

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Find number 5</Button>
    <ListView x:Name="lst" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="50">
        <ListView.Items>
            <ListViewItem>1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>4</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>5</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>6</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>7</ListViewItem>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ListViewItem)lst.Items[4]).IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ListView.ScrollIntoView to achieve what you want:

```
lst.ScrollIntoView(lst.SelectedItem);
```